# How to upgrade openssl version and link it to python 3.6.5

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, tls1.2, pyopenssl

I have several versions of python my Ubuntu machine. The default is 2.7. However, I could manage to run python 3.6 by going to a specific path which is:

```
/usr/local/bin/code/tls-client
```

I need to use `openSSL` library in my python code. I want to run specific version: `1.1.0`. I tried to use `pip install openssl` then check if the version got updated, but it is not.

```
python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, May  3 2018, 10:08:28) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016'
```

How can I link python 3.6.5 to a specific version of openSSL (say OpenSSL 1.1.0)? or even 1.1.1 (if possible)?

**EDIT:**
After compiling it from the source as the answer suggests, I checked the verison and this is what I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/openssl-1.1.0h$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

Comment: Is `OpenSSL` version `1.1.x` installed on your machine?

Comment: No. I only tried to install `openssl` through `pip` and after that I checked the version and it is not updated version (`1.0.2g`). If I have to install it manually, can you be specific on where shall I save it (which directory)?  because I installed python 3.6.5 and Ubuntu's default python when I type python is 2.7. I had to navigate to a specific directory to run python 3.6.5 (specified in the original post)

Comment: »» import ssl «« : Could be the python module `ssl`? →  maybe `python3-openssl` https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fssl.py

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you haven't updated to the most recent stable version of `OpenSSL` (from bash console):

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade openssl
```

If that doesn't install the version you expect (check by doing `openssl version -a`), then try compiling it and installing manually:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0h.tar.gz
tar xzvf openssl-1.1.0h.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.0h
./config -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)'
make
make install

openssl version -a
```

should update `OpenSSL` to version `1.1.0h` — linking should be handled automatically.

Comment: Linking even with python 3.6.5 (which is not the ubuntu's default version). I will try and update you but please keep checking.

Comment: By the way, how can I make python 3.6.5 Ubuntu's default (i.e. when I type python)? because this is not the case now. Is it the same way as upgrading openssl?

Comment: Making it the default depends on how you installed Python 3.6.5.

Comment: I think I installed it through `apt-get install` command. I am using ubuntu.

Comment: Generally an alias can suffice (e.g. in  `~/.bash_profile` add a line `alias python="/path/to/python3.6.5"`), however, it's not fool proof from problems (multiple versions of Python can tend to step on one another quite easily). You would also want to setup an alias similarly for `pip3`.

Comment: The output you show is not anything relevant (maybe try the update command again and include only that info). In your bash terminal/console type "which openssl", followed by "openssl", followed by "version". Also the `pyopenssl` package is not the same thing as the `ssl` module.

Comment: I am not getting what you mean by: `maybe try the update command again and include only that info`. However, I executed this command: `which openssl openssl version` and this is the result:`/usr/bin/openssl`

Comment: Run the command `sudo apt upgrade openssl` and show it's output. And also do `openssl`, followed by `version` and post the output.

Comment: The update command: `sudo apt update` gives:`All packages are up-to-date.`

Comment: The command `sudo apt upgrade openssl`, outputs: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.`, and the `openssl version` command outputs: `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

Comment: Okay, obviously update doesn't install the one you want, so you'll want to compile it and install manually. (see updated answer).

Comment: Sorry, is `openssl-1.1.0h` the latest stable version? how can I know? it seems to me there is `openssl-1.1.0i` in [link] (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable) Can you update the answer to allow me compile the latest version. This is important for me.

Comment: Yes it is, you can check here: https://www.openssl.org/source/. The `i` version seems to be pre-release.

Comment: I checked it. But what is in the github is another version called ending with `i`. Can you check? what does that mean? sorry for this.

Comment: That `i` version showing on GitHub appears to be a `dev` version, and it doesn't show up in the releases listing from the OpenSSL website. If you want what is considered the latest stable release version then I would go from that.

Comment: `from that` you mean the `h` version?

Answer (score 2):

This command can be used to inspect the versions of pyOpenSSL, cryptography, and the linked OpenSSL: `python -m OpenSSL.debug`